# Log regression in R using ggplot

Tags: r

Hello I need regression in R for my data 
Regression y ~ log(x) is best 
My would like to ask how do I plot regression model2 to ggplot2 bellow

```
model2 = lm(y ~ log(x), data = data)
summary(model2)
R_model2 = summary(model2)$r.squared
R_model1
R_model2
```

library(ggplot2)

```
x11()
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color = "#00AFBB", size = 1.5) + labs(x = "Počet bodů instance", size = 50, y = "Optimální počet Klustrů", title = "Regrese pro volbu parametru K") + xlim(0, 15000)+ylim(0, 10)
```

Comment: It's easier if you define log(x) as a separate variable in your data: $$data$logx = log(data$x)$$ Then use logx instead of log(x) everywhere in your code instead of log(x). Additionally, in your ggplot code, add the statement $$+ geom__smooth(method = "lm")$$ and change the label of the x-axis as needed.